# Ni-Mh batteries, low capacity better performance?

Tags: batteries, wireless, nimh, drill

When we take appart cordless things like drills, vacuum cleaners, telephones..., they often use small capacity (like 700 mAh) Ni-Mh cells. I've always thought that it was because of cost reduction, but now I'm wondering if they tolerate better the abuse of the common user that doesn't care much and plug the appliances to the charger after every use.

This question arises since I replaced the batteries of one of those devices for the ready available 2000 mAh Ni-Mh cells from a good manufacturer, and I have the feeling after some time that they have suffered an important degradation.

Anybody knows?

Comment: If your batteries have bigger capacity, then it is likely that your device is more power hungry.
Which means that the batteries are discharged/charged more often.
NiMH is said to be able to do 400/500 cycles and it is criticial not to overcharge them.

Comment: http://batteryuniversity.com/learn/article/charging_nickel_metal_hydride

Comment: What physical size were the original cells, and exactly which cells did did you replace them with? And what is the device?

Comment: The device is a vacuum cleaner. The original batteries were 10, 1.2 V AA 1300mAh, replaced with 1.2 V AA 2100 mAh.

Answer (score 1):

There's more difference between cells than good or bad quality. Cells can be built to have good energy density (store a lot of energy) or have good power density (drive a lot of output current).

Unfortunately the tweaks to the structure required to improve one generally worsen the other. An energy cell will have a lot of fine structure to give a lot of surface area to the electrodes. A power cell will require robust electrodes with large area conductors back to the terminals, which take up volume that could otherwise be storing energy.

This applies to all chemistries of cells, not just NiMH. It's especially *visible* if you browse lithium cells, as they are specified for discharge performance, modellers are interested in whether a cell can deliver 20C or 65C safely. An AA cell, because it has button terminals, cannot support a very high current. A power cell has to be soldered in, or at least connected with a special connector. This means that readily available (AA size) NiMH cells are designed for low current applications like torches and cameras, where an energy cell is appropriate. It's a quirk of history and the market that NiMH power cells tend to be built into appliances by the manufacturer, and so the power cell versions are very difficult to find on the open market.

Comment: So, if I've understood right, you suggest the degradation I observe can be due to an excess of current being drawn from standard cells? The cells I replaced for AA ones were also AA but with around half the capacity.